# Getting issue on views import?

Tags: 8, views, importing-exporting

Accidentally I have deleted the views relationship field. After that I am getting error when try to open views configuration page.

To fix the issue I have exported that view from site configuration single item and change in yml file. But when I import the changes getting below error.

> Configuration block.block.test_local_tasks depends on the test theme
> that will not be installed after import.

> Configuration block.block.test_main_menu depends on the test theme that will not be installed after import.

> Configuration block.block.test_messages depends on the test theme that will not be installed after import.

> Configuration block.block.test_powered depends on the test theme that will not be installed after import.

Please suggest.

Comment: It looks like you deleted some blocks too.  If the view isn't too complicated, I would just re-create it manually-- and in the future, always export + commit config (including views) in version control (e.g., git); that way, if you have this problem again, you can just revert the site based on your exported config, which will fix this problem in less than a minute.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick for your suggestion. Will do same next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am able to fix it by deleting the old(not in use) block present in config table.

```
DELETE FROM config WHERE name IN ( 'block.block.batra_uae_local_tasks', 'block.block.batra_uae_main_menu', 'block.block.batra_uae_messages', 'block.block.batra_uae_powered' );
```

Get help from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2694895 page.